# Understanding `list[x][y]`

Tags: python, indexing

I was looking at making a maze game in python, and on an online tutorial there was a `list` that seemed to be indexed twice. I understand that `list[x]` pulls the `x` item from that list, but I don't know how double brackets like `list[x][y]` work.
Does it pull the `y` of the `x` of `list`?

Can someone please tell me what it's called so I can further research it?

Comment: _"Does it pull the y of the x of list?"_ - yes. It doesn't have a particular name, it's just indexing, _twice_. Add parentheses or extract a variable if that helps you clarify it.

Comment: A list of lists - `[[1]]`

Comment: `list[x]` produces another value that can be indexed; it's just a short form of `t = list[x]; t[y]`

Comment: It means the `list` is a 2D two dimension list.  eg. `matrix = [[1,2], [3,4]]`  that's why you will need two indexing.  How do you access number `2`?  <--  `matrix[0][1]`

Comment: It's a *nested* list, not a two-dimensional list. You index one list, then you index the list produced by the first. A Numpy array is an example of a two-dimensional data structure which you can index along either access immediately.

Comment: Is it difficult to understand `3 * 4 * 5`? No; it just does `3 * 4`, and then applies `* 5` to the result. List indexing is the same. There isn't a special term for it, or anything to research, just like there isn't a special term for making two consecutive right turns when following driving directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Imagine we have a list with sublists in them. For example:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

If we want to access one of those numbers, let's say 6, and assign it to the variable *b*, we would select it like this:

```
b = a[1][2]
```

The one means the 2nd element in the list *a* and the two would mean the 3rd element in the list we selected from a.

I hope this solves your problem and happy coding!